# Is it possible to Create a 3 dimensional array with negative numbers in C++

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, dynamic-arrays

hey so I currently have a 3D array of objects but I want to make it so half the indices are negative. I'm pretty sure I saw something about how negative arrrays can cause errors and crashes is this true aswell?
this is the code I have for making my array if that helps in any way.

```
    //creates 3 dimensional array
 vGrid = new Vox * *[arraySize];
for (int x = 0; x < arraySize; x++)
{

    vGrid[x] = new Vox * [arraySize];

    for (int y = 0; y < arraySize; y++)
    {

        vGrid[x][y] = new Vox[arraySize];
    }

}
```

any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: *hey so I currently have a 3D array of objects but I want to make it so half the indices are negative* -- This is getting into [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) territory

Comment: Hint: if you have a pointer `Vox *p=new Vox[10];`, you end up with `p[0]` through `p[9]`. But if you add five to it:  `Vox *p=new Vox[10]; p += 5;`, now you have `p[-5]` through `p[4]` as, seemingly, an array with negative indexes. Does it look like that to you? It sure does. It really isn't, but it's a good simulation. Simply extend the same principle in multiple dimensions, and call it a day. Oh, you'll still have to remember to `delete` what got `new`ed, and it must be the same original pointer, not an offset. This is a lot of hard, error-prone work, but this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so you want a 3D Cartesian space with positive and negative coordinates.  You can write a class to implement this:

```
class Space {
public:
    Space(int len) : _vox(len*len*len), _len(len) {}
    Vox& operator()(int x, int y, int z);
private:
    std::vector<Vox> _vox;
    int _len;
};
```

This creates len^3 Vox objects, but in a single vector which is safer and more efficient than a C-style array of pointers to pointers.

The `operator()` is an indexing function which can be used like this:

```
Space space(51); // 3D: 51x51x51, valid indexes [-25..25]
Vox& vox = space(10, -5, 0);
// ... do things with the Vox at those coordinates
```

I use `()` instead of `[]` because `operator[]` can only take a single argument, and we'd rather take three arguments for more natural 3D indexing.  Implement the indexing operator like this:

```
Vox& Space::operator()(int x, int y, int z)
{
    // shift the "natural" input coordinates into "storage" coordinates
    x += _len / 2; // 10 becomes 35
    y += _len / 2; // -5 becomes 20
    z += _len / 2; // 0 becomes 25
    return _vox.at(x + y*_len + z*_len*_len); // index linear storage as 3D
}
```

I used `at()` instead of `[]` because it checks the range for you and throws an exception if you exceed the range.